# Do I need to update a Mew wallet that is 4 years old? What do I need to do to access the wallet?

Tags: upgrading

My (MEW) wallet is on an offline computer. Can I still sign a transaction offline? I cannot find anything on updating old MEW wallets. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should work. The network remains compatible with previous transactions. In any case the most important thing are the private key or seed phrase, with that you should be able to migrate to another wallet if it is needed. Check their website but it seems they still support using it offline [Making an Offline Transaction](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/offline/offline_transaction/).